# SublimeText2 plugin settings: Escape Dollar sign for a regex in DocBlockr plugin's settings

Tags: python, regex, escaping, sublimetext, sublimetext2

[DocBlockr](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs#readme) 
for [SublimeText2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)
lets you declare your custom variable type rules based on the name of the variable.

From the README:

```
"jsdocs_notation_map": [{
  "regex": "tbl_?[Rr]ow", // any arbitrary regex to test against the var name
  "type": "TableRow"      // you can add your own types
}]
```

I want to catch variables that start with the `$` character

*example:*

```
"jsdocs_notation_map": [{
  "regex": "^[$].+",      // any word that starts with $
  "type": "HTMLElement"   // That is its type
}]
```

So that the `$header` will be caught from the above regex.

Unfortunately the above does not work. The plugin won't recognize my `$header` variable 
as an "HTMLElement".

I have tried the following regex strings:

- `$` - It matches everything, even varnames with no `$` inside them.
- `\\$`
- `\\\\$`
- `$$`
- `\\$$`
- `\\\\$$`
- `[$]`
- `[\\$]`

*Sidenote: The editor won't let me insert odd numbers of `\`.*

All of them match nothing, except for the first that matches everything.

This is not a RegEx question. The RegExs that should work, *(ex: `^[$].+`)* simply do not work because of the $ character. I think it has to do with the plugin settings mechanism and how the $ is used by the python parsing mechanism.

*Sidenote: The `"^[.].+"` RegEx works as expected.*

Any help is most welcome

PS: If anyone can be of help, i would like the "^" in the start of the regex string. I don't think that it won't work out of the box, but if not, please share the knowledge on that as well.

Comment: I edited your regexes to be inline code - I'm not sure how many backslashes you originally meant to show, since SO was stripping out some. You might want to double check that they're as you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh hey... so what the plugin does is strip any leading `$` or `_` from the variable/function name and then apply the regex. This was added so that `_foo` `$foo` and `foo` could all be recognised with the same regex, since at the time, I didn't think about those characters having special meaning. Looks like it's actually a complete misfeature in the end. Looks like you've spent a bit of time hacking on it, sorry 'bout that.

I've [added it to the issue tracker](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs/issues/66) now. In the future, that would be a good way to get my attention, too :)

Comment: This has been fixed and deployed now. Let me know if there are any problems.

Answer (score 0):

$ is end of line so you might try putting it in square brackets as an alternative attempt to escape it... so something like [$][^\s]+

Answer (score 0):

`"\\$"` should work. The first `\` escapes the second one for use in JSON. This then produces the regex `\$`, which matches a literal dollar.

Answer (score 0):

`"^[$].*"`

The `^` forces a match against the beginning of the line. The `[]` here serve to escape the `$` (it's easier than figuring out how many layers of backslashes you need), and the `+*` matches everything that follows. You could replace the `.*` with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` if you wanted to match one or more alphanumeric/underscore characters.

Comment: ^ is start of line \^ is start of string.

Comment: In general yes, I will edit to make it clearer. In this case `matched = re.search(rule['regex'], name)` [here](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs/blob/f9f4aa6747915fc09f3484d74f13bc7acc2c86e3/jsdocs.py#L279) the start of the string *is* the start of the line. `v = "$my_variable"; re.search("^[$].*", v)` *does* return a match. (I'm making an assumption that, in the code linked above, `name` refers to a token and not an entire line of text.)

Comment: I understand the above. Unfortunately if the regex has the $ sign in it, it won't work as expected, used inside the plugin settings file.